# I am taking Cs50 lecture3 Django in which there is a problem that not works the name variable we assigned to each path in urls.py, and create a link

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

**this is my django+html code**

```
   {% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

   {% block body %}
    
    <h1>Tasks Lists</h1>
    <a href="[% url 'tasks:add' %]"> Add a task</a>
   {% endblock %}
```

> this is where i use varriable name add and link it to another page.

**Urls.py**

```
     from django.urls import path
     from . import views


 app_name = "tasks"
 urlpatterns=[
   path("",views.index,name="index"),
   path("add",views.add,name="add")

              ]
```

this is where i use the varriable name "add".

Answer (score 0):

A [*template tag* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#tags) is written between *curly* brackets, so It is `{% … %}`, not `[% … %]`, you thus write this as:

```
<a href="{% url 'tasks:add' %}"> Add a task</a>
```

Comment: Brother, But it then Return Me an Error ('set' object is not reversible) So thats why I use it Then It works.

Comment: Bro Plz Give me any Solution that what i use so the problem Become solve because when i not use [% %] then it also give me an error.